# Enable/disable two more SwitchPreference when one switch Preference is enabled

Tags: android, android-preferences, switchpreference

When one preference is selected, other two preferences should be available for clicks, otherwise the should be shady/dim so that the user knows they are not clickable. Like how we set alpha for text.
Attached the code below. Please Let me know if there is a solution.

```
<PreferenceCategory
        android:title="@string/category_dnd_title"
        app:iconSpaceReserved="false">

        <androidx.preference.SwitchPreferenceCompat
            android:defaultValue="false"
            android:key="key1"
            android:title="title1" />

        <androidx.preference.SwitchPreferenceCompat
            android:defaultValue="false"
            android:dependency="key1"
            android:key="key2"
            android:title="title2" />

        <androidx.preference.SwitchPreferenceCompat
            android:defaultValue="false"
            android:dependency="key1"
            android:key="@key3"
            android:title="title3"/>
    </PreferenceCategory>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this, you need some fragment class to manage your preferences in code.

```
public class PreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat {

    @Override
    public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, String rootKey) {
        setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.your_xml, rootKey);
        
        final SharedPreferences preferences = androidx.preference.PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());

        // dont forget to check nullity in real app production, findPreference could return null
        final SwitchPreferenceCompat switchPreference1 = (SwitchPreferenceCompat) findPreference("key1");
        final SwitchPreferenceCompat switchPreference2 = (SwitchPreferenceCompat) findPreference("key2");
        final SwitchPreferenceCompat switchPreference3 = (SwitchPreferenceCompat) findPreference("key3");
        if (preferences.getBoolean("key1", false)) {
            switchPreference2.setEnabled(true);
            switchPreference3.setEnabled(true);
        } else {
            switchPreference2.setEnabled(false);
            switchPreference3.setEnabled(false);
        }
        switchPreference1.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
                boolean turned = (Boolean) newValue;
                if (turned) {
                    switchPreference2.setEnabled(true);
                    switchPreference3.setEnabled(true);
                } else {
                    switchPreference2.setEnabled(false);
                    switchPreference3.setEnabled(false);
                }
                preferences.edit().putBoolean("key1", turned).apply();
                return true;
            }
        });

    }
}
```

@EDIT
You can override an SwitchPreferenceCompat class to make an enabled/disabled effect

```
public class CustomSwitchPreference extends SwitchPreferenceCompat {

    public CustomSwitchPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle, defStyleRes);
    }

    public CustomSwitchPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public CustomSwitchPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CustomSwitchPreference(Context context) {
        super(context, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(PreferenceViewHolder holder) {
        super.onBindViewHolder(holder);
        TextView title = (TextView) holder.findViewById(android.R.id.title);
        TextView summary = (TextView) holder.findViewById(android.R.id.summary);
        if (title.isEnabled()) {
            title.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        } else {
            title.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
        }

        if (summary.isEnabled()) {
            summary.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        } else {
            summary.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
        }
    }
}
```

In that case your preference xml should look like this

```
<PreferenceCategory
    android:title="Category"
    app:iconSpaceReserved="false"
    >

    <com.test.CustomSwitchPreference
        android:defaultValue="false"
        android:key="key1"
        android:title="title1"
        />

    <com.test.CustomSwitchPreference
        android:defaultValue="false"
        android:key="key2"
        android:title="title2"
        />

    <com.test.CustomSwitchPreference
        android:defaultValue="false"
        android:key="key3"
        android:title="title3"
        />

</PreferenceCategory>
```

And you should change an access to the preference in fragment like

```
    final CustomSwitchPreference switchPreference1 = (CustomSwitchPreference) findPreference("key1");
    final CustomSwitchPreference switchPreference2 = (CustomSwitchPreference) findPreference("key2");
    final CustomSwitchPreference switchPreference3 = (CustomSwitchPreference) findPreference("key3");
```

Comment: Hey, I have tried it but I don't  see anything different from adding a dependent.
I am unable to access the other two preferences yes, but the shady/dim of the text part I am not getting

Comment: Which api do you test? By default this should be gray, when is disabled. Maybe you have some style that makes it not working.

Comment: The toggle is becoming grey, but the title is still bold. In my use case I have ListPreference, there the title is always bold.

Comment: Try to override an `SwitchPreferenceCompat` class. Look my edit.